# How can I get the coordinates of a location on the grid?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, coordinates

How can I get the coordinates of a location on the grid with the number of one box?

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6  
------------------------------
1|  1  2  3  4  5  6  
2|  7  8  9 10 11 12 
3| 13 14 15 16 17 18
4| 19 20 21 22 23 24
5| 25 26 27 28 29 30
6| 31 32 33 34 35 36
```

i.e: if I have the number 15, the coordinates are x=3;y=3

I tried developing a function, but it's not working, does someone have an idea?

Thanks you for your help

Comment: you can use 2d array ? Let's see your code

Comment: Zoners, usually it helps to also add what you have tried already (the function you mentioned) that way we see your attempt so far and if it is "close" you can see that you were on the right track...

Comment: @Kay I detect one problem, if the number is 6 with your function: x=0 and y=2 and the truth response must be x=6 and y=0 if the number equals 6

Comment: @Zoners: `y=0`? I thought x and y start with 1. However, [my query](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13763586/284240) returns `X:6 Y:1` for 6.

Comment: @Zoners Yes I noticed this as well. I changed my answer and added some explanation

Comment: @Zoners, please use the comments section on Kay's answer if the subject isn't general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE (Formula was wrong):**

```
y = (myNumber - 1) / 6 + 1;
x = (myNumber - 1) % 6 + 1;
```

---

**UPDATE (Explanation):**

Every row contains 6 elements. We define x as remainder when dividing by 6:

x ~ myNumber % 6

and add +1 as the definition range is [1;6].

x ~ myNumber % 6 + 1

But the last element in the row is divisible by 6 without remainder. To consider this we subtract 1 from myNumber before applying the modulo operator:

**x = (myNumber - 1) % 6 + 1**

e.g. myNumber = 1 => x = 1; myNumber = 6 => x = 6; myNumber = 7 => x = 1; myNumber = 12 => x = 6;

The number of rows is called y and is proportional to the integer division by 6:

y ~ myNumber / 6

But again we we have to consider that we are not starting at 0 but at 1:

y ~ myNumber / 6 + 1

And again there is the 'left shift' as the last element of each row can be divided by 6 without remainder. So we subtract 1 from myNumber before dividing to reflect this:

**y = (myNumber - 1) / 6 + 1**

Comment: But has no explanation. Bad answer. (To clarify: This is the right answer, just not a good one)

Comment: @Ruirize +1 for demanding some explanation. But to clarify: The first version wasn't the right answer as it had a bug ;-)

Comment: +0.5 for answer speed, +0.5 for correcting the answer and explaining it. Total score: +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a jagged array:

```
private static readonly int[][] matrix = new int[6][];

// ...

matrix[0] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
matrix[1] = new int[] { 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
matrix[2] = new int[] { 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 };
matrix[3] = new int[] { 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 };
matrix[4] = new int[] { 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 };
matrix[5] = new int[] { 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36 };
```

and Linq to find the x and y values:

```
int num = 15;
var matches = matrix
    .Select((yArr, index) => new { yArr, yPos = index + 1 })
    .Where(y => y.yArr.Contains(num))
    .Select(y => new
    {
        X = (y.yArr.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
                   .First(x => x.x == num).i) + 1,
        Y = y.yPos,
    });

if(matches.Any())
{
    var firstMatch = matches.First();
    int x = firstMatch.X;
    int y = firstMatch.Y;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/QIaymk)